# Trying to practice PHP and SQL- I am not sure if I get the logic right

Tags: php, sql

I googled a short tutorial to connect a database and then I wanted to compare the username and password to then can gain access. It is kind of novice coding, but at least I can practice and hopefully pick up programming more.

check.php

```
<?php
    //Need session//

    $username = 'root';
    $password = 'root';
    $host = 'localhost';
    $db_name = 'pcart';

    $connection = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) or die('cannot be connected');

    mysql_select_db($db_name, $connection) or die ('Could not select database');
    $user=$_POST['username'];
    $pass=$_POST['password'];

    $query = "Select username, password from tbladmins";
    $user_result = mysql_query($query);
    echo $user_result;
    if (mysql_num_rows($user_result)==0)
    {
        echo "no rows to print";
    }
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($user_result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
        $checkuser=$row["username"];
        $checkpass=$row["password"];
    }
    mysql_free_result($user_result);

    if !($user == $checkuser and $pass == $checkpass)
    {
        echo'where are you';
        $results= mysql_query("Select * from tbladmins;") or die('error connecting to mysql');
        if(mysql_num_rows($results)==0)
        {
             echo "no rows found, nothing to print so i am exiting";
        }
        print "test successful"
        mysql_free_result($results);
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Wrong user or password! If you forgot, email Josephine for the username
        and password";
    }
?>
```

index.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Partner Portal
        </title>
    </head>
    <body id="partners-page">
        <div id="main">
            <form method="post" action="Check.php">
                <input type="text" name="username" value=""/>
                <input type="password" name="password" value=""/>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
                <input type="reset" name="reset" value="reset">
            </form>
            <a href="#">forgotten password</a>

        </div>
        <!--#main-->

        </div><!--div partner-page-->
</html>
```

**EDIT**

The problem is that it won't show anything when I am testing if username and password match the one in database... So did I overlook anything? Why was the page blank when I tested inputting username and password?

Comment: You misspellted $locahost = 'localhost'; in dbconfig.php, it must be $localhost = 'localhost';

Comment: Consider using PDO for database connections.

Comment: @Yorirou, What is PDO? I am sorry if I am ignorant but I just started writing codes.

Comment: @Sarah, yes i know i have corrected it..

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php This is a very useful API, it is really worth to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice Josephine, that's a great start! Now I know you have heard of the saying, there are a million ways to skin a cat, and this is no exception. There are really a lot of ways to accomplish the above but as of late, this method of doing it have become a bit, how should I say it, un-secure.

Database connection and user management and implementing it all in a secure way is now contained in every PHP framework you can find. This is all done for you so basically what you have to do is fill in the configuration file and you are good to go.

Saying that, it's great to learn how it all ties together and you are on the right track. :D

A framework is there to re-use code that you use in every application, and being a software engineer, we re-use a lot, so you do not want to go and duplicate it all over the place.

Another thing is that the code like this, stays hidden so for instance, I, can't muck it up and I know it's tested properly.

Keep up the good work :D It gets ***a lot*** more interesting the deeper you go down the rabbit hole.

Comment: yea i know but my code doesn't work because it shows blank when i am trying to test. which php framework works better with pinnaclecart database when it is outside pinnaclecart?

Comment: Try var_dump($_POST) and use $_POST instead of $_REQUEST

Comment: yes i already changed to $_POST but nothing happens :( i am still figuring it out...

Comment: `if !($user == $checkuser and $pass == $checkpass)` Your check is wrong also ;) 'and' in PHP is && and I would rewrite the if statement as `if ( $user === $checkuser && $pass === $checkpass )`

Answer (score 0):

Josephine, for the base/groundwork yes.  You can always add [MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) / [SHA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Hash_Algorithm) to hash your password for better security.

Comment: @Gray Tsui, how to add md5/sha? Im not familiar with this. I google it up

Comment: Hi MD5/SHA is one of the standard hashing methods (for encryption/ciphering).  in PHP, you can call md5($str) or sha1($str).  You are most certainly welcome to echo md5($str) or sha1($str) and see the effects.   G'luck.

Comment: @Gray Tsui, not only plain md5/sha, but with salt

Answer (score 0):

The only obvious reason I can see that it would fail is the typo here (*locah-*, instead of *localh-*):

```
$locahost = 'localhost';
```

It's a good start, but it looks like you've still got a long journey ahead of you.

Some of the obvious things are:

1) Why name a variable containing 'localhost' as $localhost? It would make more sense to have called this $host

2) indeed, the variables passed to `mysql_connect` *are only ever used* for `mysql_connect` - why did you not use literals? Why are the variable declarations and function invocation split across two separate include files?

3) Why have you not provided a specific error message? One was probably generated at some point during the execution - if you saw it then you should have provided it in your post. If you didn't see it, then spend some time thinking about why (and make sure you will see it next time).

4) Once you've got it working on your test rig, how do you think the script is going to perform when you've got a few thousand rows in tbladmin? While performing complex tasks using non-procedural code can result in code that is difficult to debug, pushing more logic down the tier almost always improves performance. Consider:

```
 $qry = "SELECT * from tbladmins WHERE username='"
        . mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['username'], $connection)
        . "' AND password = '"
        . mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['password'], $connection)
        . "'";
```

5) using inline code within include files is a messy practice - if you restrict include files to only declaring functions, classes and constants then explicitly invoke them at the right time, then you'll save yourself a lot grief as your programs become more complex.

6) include files are not a substitute for modular programming - see also (5) above.

Good luck.

Comment: I noticed that and I have put everything back in one file together (check.php) instead of separating the files. As for #3, I only see white and blank page so I couldn't figure why it is. I am still figuring till now. I know but the admins are used for testing. What you said is true because it will be same if it is for partners.